# slice() method is not working inside react class based component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, slice

I am facing a bug that I cant use the .slice() method of javascript in react, basically I call the slice() method inside a function in class-based component, and the function in which I put the slice is passed to 2 levels down child component and triggered from there onClick event but the issue is that the slice method is not doing its work of removing element it just consoles the same array, here I show you the code in simple concept,

```js
useSlice = () => {
  let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  console.log(arr.slice(1, 1));
}

useSlice()
```

this code print the same values of the array in the console instead of displaying the modified array.
What to do ???

Comment: Post your whole code.

Comment: It is difficult from information to debug thhis pls post relevant code

Comment: Please read the documentaion

Answer (score 5):

You should read more detail about how splice work at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

The second param in slice is end index (exclusive). So, if you arr.slice(1,1): mean slice from index 1 to index *just before* 1 will always return empty array.

By the way, if you want to remove element. You should use 'splice' instead.

Answer (score 2):

`arr.slice(1,1)` returns `[]`, as it should. You're starting at element 1 and ending at element 1, which is zero elements. This is effectively range 1-0, which you can't do.